# CloudFoundry vcap loadbalance in mysql

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, cloud-foundry

is there anyone knows that how mysql in cloud foundry (vcap.me, not cloudfoundry.com) can do load balance or not?

I mean, does cloud foundry can take this automatically? or we need to do something to dispatch our data manually?

thanks a lot if you could give me some advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of yet there is no support for load balancing or clustering between multiple instances of MySQL. This may be a feature considered for a future release.

Comment: okay, thanks for your answer
hope it could support as soon as possible!